# Can Angular ng-if check if the value contains something?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got the following in my template:

```
<td ng-if="invoice.paymentMethod == 'automatic'">{{ invoice.paid | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss' }}</td>
<td ng-if="invoice.paymentMethod != 'automatic'">{{ invoice.paid | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</td>
```

It shows the payment date in a different formate (with time) when the the payment was made automatically.

But: in the future, this "invoice.paymentMethod" can become something like "automatic - ideal" or "automatic - paypal".

So, can't I make a ng-if so that it checks if invoice.paymentMethod CONTAINS "automatic" instead of be equal to it? Should be easy but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case ngSwitch will works perfectly please see documention here

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

or see that demo: http://jsbin.com/qejoza/1/edit or here http://jsbin.com/qejoza/2/edit

HTML:

```
 <table ng-repeat="invoice in invoices" ng-switch on="invoice.paymentMethod">
    <tr>
      <td ng-switch-when="automatic">automatic: {{ invoice.paid | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss' }}</td>
      <td ng-switch-when="automatic-ebay">ebay: {{ invoice.paid | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss' }}</td>
      <td ng-switch-when="automatic-paypal">paypal:{{ invoice.paid | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss' }}</td>
    </tr>  
  <table>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){


 $scope.invoices=[{

   paymentMethod: 'automatic-paypal',
   paid: "16/01/2014"
 },
                 {

   paymentMethod: 'automatic-ebay',
   paid: "16/01/2014"
 },
                 {

   paymentMethod: 'automatic',
   paid: "16/01/2014"
 }];


});
```

Comment: Not exactly what I meant but a great solution, for other code duplication in our project as well!! Thanks a lot, I wasn't aware of this command.